# Android: How to change a button so that it has a graphic image embedded on it

Tags: android, image, graphics, button

I have a program that I'm writing in Android using Eclipse.  It has an array of buttons (4x4).
I would like to have the buttons contain a user defined image (perhaps some filled circles).

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#CustomButton

Should be straight forward enough to follow.. if the image is chosen by the uesr, you will just have to change the image path on a button press or something similar

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Andrew I think this may be one way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. I want to have text as well as the button image.